# Калькулятор на Javascript расчета стоимости работ и материала по устройству пола в зависимости от площади

Tags: javascript, html, html5, form

Всем привет, я здесь новичок и пишу свой один из первых простеньких калькуляторов.
Написал код Javascript:

```js
var wasUsed = false;

function doCalc() {

  var meterPlus = 0;
  var totalMaterial = 0;
  var totalWorks = 0;
  var userInputSquare = $('#square').val();
  if ($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 500) {
    meterPlus = 3055;
  } else {
    meterPlus = 2706;
  }
  if ($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 500) {
    totalMaterial = (userInputSquare * meterPlus) * 52 / 100;
  } else {
    totalMaterial = (userInputSquare * meterPlus) * 57 / 100;
  }
  if ($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 500) {
    totalWorks = (userInputSquare * meterPlus) * 48 / 100;
  } else {
    totalWorks = (userInputSquare * meterPlus) * 43 / 100;
  }
  var totalPrice = userInputSquare * meterPlus;

  $('#meter').html(meterPlus);
  $('#material').html(totalMaterial);
  $('#works').html(totalWorks);
  $('#calcPrice').html(totalPrice);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('input', '#square, #material, #works, #calcPrice', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
    if ($(this).val() > 9999) {
      $(this).val(1);
    }
    doCalc();
  });


  $("input[name=texture]:radio").change(function() {
    doCalc();
  });

  wasUsed = true; // init calc while not sending Yandex Goal
  doCalc();
  wasUsed = false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex-1 mxl-2">
  <div class="configurator" id="calcForm">
    <div id="question-1" class="question">
      <p>Введите площадь пола (м<sup>2</sup>)</p>
      <input class="form-control bg-white mb-3 registration-input-box" type="number" id="square" name="square" value="502" />
    </div>
    <div id="question-2" class="question">
      <p>Стоимость руб./м<sup>2</sup>:</p>
      <textarea class="form-control bg-white mb-3 registration-input-box" id="meter" name="meter" /></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="question-3" class="question">
      <p>Стоимость материалов (руб.):</p>
      <textarea class="form-control bg-white mb-3 registration-input-box" id="material" name="material" /></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="question-4" class="question">
      <p>Стоимость работ (руб.):</p>
      <textarea class="form-control bg-white mb-3 registration-input-box" id="works" name="works" /></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="question-5" class="question">
      <p>Общая стоимость (руб.):</p>
      <textarea class="form-control bg-white mb-3 registration-input-box" id="calcPrice" name="calcPrice" /></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Формула взята из Excel, сейчас расчет производится в нем](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCuGh.jpg)

[Однако на сайте скрипт не срабатывает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oafR4.jpg)

**Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу, что не так написал? Где ошибка?**

Списывал код калькулятора с аналогичного сайта, только там расчет потолка, тоже в зависимости от площади. Там код работает...

Comment: Не работает почему? Какие то ошибки выдает или считает не правильно?

Comment: Вообще не реагирует на введенные данные площади. В консоли браузера ошибок нет...

Comment: На момент вызова $(document).on('input', '#square, #material, #works, #calcPrice'... эти элементы присутствуют в документе? Они выводятся в консоль, например так: console.log($('#square')); ?

Comment: Спасибо, все работает! Встал вопрос, как выводить посчитанные значения разделяя их на разряды?